# Get a dataframe of the sum of each indivicual column to then compare with other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the sum of each column in a new dataframe to then make comparations with other dataframe.
Data:

```
      name   name1   name2    name3   name4
T      56     98      81       57       80
N1     39     13      92       12       71
N2    149     11       9       10       18

Expected result(df1):
          name   name1   name2    name3   name4
   Total   244    122     182      79      169
```

After get this result I want to compare with other df.

```
df1:
          name   name1   name2    name3   name4
   Total   244    122     182      79      169

df2:
            name   name1   name2    name3   name4
True_Total   245    121     182      79      168
```

Then I need to get and out put with the values that match and the others that did not such as:

```
The values did not match in:
            name   name1   name2    name3   name4
     Total   244    122     182      79      169
True_Total   245    121     182      79      168
 Difference   1      1       0       0         1
```

The values did not match with the True_Total in name, name1 and name3. Check your data before compare.

**Note**: What I need is a function. I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for transpose:

```
df11 = df1.sum().to_frame('Total').T
```

For compare with another `df` with same columns join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then subtract selected rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df11, df2])
df.loc['Difference'] = df.loc['Total'].sub(df.loc['True_Total']).abs()
print (df)
            name  name1  name2  name3  name4
Total        244    122    182     79    169
True_Total   245    121    182     79    168
Difference     1      1      0      0      1
```